# Localization of Display Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to Localize my properties name in PropertyGrid. 
.cs

```
[Display(Name = "Date Received")] //ori
public DateTime DateReceived { get; set; }
```

.cshtml

```
<label class="label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateReceived) : </label>
```

When i try add `[Display(ResourceType = typeof(SharedResources), Name = "DateReceived")]` error message `InvalidOperationException: Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed. Type 'BeyondEdge.Web.SharedResources' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'DateReceived'.`
Is there any part is wrong in my code? or is there any other way to Localize my properties name in.cs?

Comment: Can you show `BeyondEdge.Web.SharedResources`?

Comment: @Sascha under sharedResources.cs is empty, but created a .resx file

Comment: Can you expand the .resx file and find a generated cs file?

Comment: @RossBush Cant, the .resx file cant be expand

Answer (score 0):

Can you right click the .resx file and select properties to ensure that the correct T4 template is being applied for generating the resource classes. If there is not an autogenerated code file then your application code has nothing to latch onto from your resources.

[image]

Comment: by `@localizer["Date"]` in .cshtml can work, but localize in PropertyGrid error occur. \Not really sure but my Custom Tool Namespace is empty

Comment: The custom tool is used during the build when creating satellite assemblies. I think that is what you are trying to achieve above. If you build with the settings above, are new files created?